# MySql and creating Foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

```
    -- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Sun Apr  2 17:50:54 2017
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema SintalDB
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema SintalDB
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `SintalDB` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci ;
USE `SintalDB` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `SintalDB`.`User`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SintalDB`.`User` (
  `PK_User` INT NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `Surname` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `Phone_Nr` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
  `Car_Reg_Nr` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `Username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Servis_Input_Rights` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `Servis_Output_Rights` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `Servis_Delete_Rights` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `Admin_Rights` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_User`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_slovenian_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `SintalDB`.`City`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SintalDB`.`City` (
  `PK_City` INT NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_City`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_slovenian_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `SintalDB`.`Company`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SintalDB`.`Company` (
  `PK_Company` INT NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Address_Nr` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  `FK_City` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Company`),
  INDEX `FK_City_Company_fkn_idx` (`FK_City` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_City_Company_fkn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_City`)
    REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`City` (`PK_City`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_slovenian_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `SintalDB`.`Facility`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SintalDB`.`Facility` (
  `PK_Facility_AD` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Address_Nr` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  `FK_City` INT NOT NULL,
  `FK_Company_Affiliation` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Facility_AD`),
  INDEX `FK_City_Facility_fkn_idx` (`FK_City` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_Company_Affiliation_Facility_fkn_idx` (`FK_Company_Affiliation` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_City_Facility_fkn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_City`)
    REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`City` (`PK_City`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Company_Affiliation_Facility_fkn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Company_Affiliation`)
    REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`Company` (`PK_Company`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_slovenian_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `SintalDB`.`Servis`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SintalDB`.`Servis` (
  `PK_Servis_Nr` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Facility_AD` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `Description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Date_Recived` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `FK_User_Commited` INT NULL,
  `Date_Commited` DATETIME NULL,
  `FK_User_Done` INT NULL,
  `Date_Done` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Servis_Nr`),
  INDEX `FK_User_Servis_fkn_idx` (`FK_User_Commited` ASC, `FK_User_Done` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_Facility_Servis_fkn_idx` (`FK_Facility_AD` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_User_Servis_fkn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_User_Commited` , `FK_User_Done`)
    REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`User` (`PK_User` , `PK_User`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Facility_Servis_fkn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Facility_AD`)
    REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`Facility` (`PK_Facility_AD`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_slovenian_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `SintalDB`.`ServisNote`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SintalDB`.`ServisNote` (
  `PK_ServisNote` INT NOT NULL,
  `Note` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `FK_User_Note` INT NOT NULL,
  `Date_Created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `FK_Servis_Nr` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_ServisNote`),
  INDEX `FK_Servis_ServisNote_fkn_idx` (`FK_Servis_Nr` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_User_ServisNote_fkn_idx` (`FK_User_Note` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Servis_ServisNote_fkn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Servis_Nr`)
    REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`Servis` (`PK_Servis_Nr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_User_ServisNote_fkn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_User_Note`)
    REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`User` (`PK_User`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_slovenian_ci;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

**this is my sql file and I get error after i run sql file**

Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

> 17:52:08  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SintalDB`.`Servis` (
>   `PK_Servis_Nr` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,   `FK_Facility_AD` VARCHAR(6) NOT
>   NULL,   `Description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,   `Date_Recived` DATETIME
>   NOT NULL,   `FK_User_Commited` INT NULL,   `Date_Commited` DATETIME
>   NULL,   `FK_User_Done` INT NULL,   `Date_Done` DATETIME NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Servis_Nr`),   INDEX `FK_User_Servis_fkn_idx`
>   (`FK_User_Commited` ASC, `FK_User_Done` ASC),   INDEX
>   `FK_Facility_Servis_fkn_idx` (`FK_Facility_AD` ASC),   CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_User_Servis_fkn`     FOREIGN KEY (`FK_User_Commited` ,
>   `FK_User_Done`)     REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`User` (`PK_User` ,
>   `PK_User`)     ON DELETE NO ACTION     ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_Facility_Servis_fkn`     FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Facility_AD`)
>   REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`Facility` (`PK_Facility_AD`)     ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION     ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET
>   = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_slovenian_ci    Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.063 sec

Answer (score 2):

Check this: [Adding foreign key on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023481/adding-foreign-key-on-multiple-columns)

I think you must add two foreign key for made reference to the same column.
You can replace your code for this and test.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `SintalDB`.`Servis`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SintalDB`.`Servis` (
  `PK_Servis_Nr` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Facility_AD` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `Description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Date_Recived` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `FK_User_Commited` INT NULL,
  `Date_Commited` DATETIME NULL,
  `FK_User_Done` INT NULL,
  `Date_Done` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Servis_Nr`),
  INDEX `FK_User_Servis_fkn_idx` (`FK_User_Commited` ASC, `FK_User_Done` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_Facility_Servis_fkn_idx` (`FK_Facility_AD` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_User_Servis_fkn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_User_Commited`)
    REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`User` (`PK_User` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_User_Servis_2_fkn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_User_Done`)
    REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`User` (`PK_User`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Facility_Servis_fkn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Facility_AD`)
    REFERENCES `SintalDB`.`Facility` (`PK_Facility_AD`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_slovenian_ci;
```

Comment: I agree.  `FOREIGN KEY (FK_User_Commited, FK_User_Done) REFERENCES SintalDB.User (PK_User, PK_User)` doesn't make sense, on multiple levels.